# Can a prior be conjugate and noninformative at the same time?

Tags: conjugate-prior

And if so, could somebody give me a concrete example?

Comment: It depends on what you regard as noninformative, and in some cases whether you require the prior to be proper.  To take the example of a binomial likelihood, the conjugate distribution is a beta distribution, and some people regard a uniform Beta(1,1) as uninformative, some might use a Jeffreys Beta(0.5,0.5) prior, and some a Haldane improper Beta(0,0) prior.  But since these are different, others might argue that simply choosing one would be informative

Comment: @Henry you should make it an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*As requested in comments:*

It depends on what you regard as noninformative, and in some cases whether you require the prior to be proper.

To take the example of a binomial likelihood, the conjugate distribution is a beta distribution, and

- some people regard a uniform $\text{Beta}(1,1)$ as uninformative,
- some might use a Jeffreys $\text{Beta}(0.5,0.5)$ prior, and
- some a Haldane improper $\text{Beta}(0,0)$ prior.

But since these are different, others might argue that simply choosing one would be informative.